# Getting an error when installing MariaDB on Centos 8

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, centos8

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

See the image below:

[image]

Same for MySQL:

```
sudo yum install mysql
```

View image here:

[image]

Comment: Does [this help](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-mariadb-on-centos-8/)? (case-sensitive name issue, perhaps, with the install command?)

Comment: Try `yum update && yum upgrade -y` first - maybe your system catalogue is out of date.